# Engine/model information for lawnmower

Tags: engine, small-engine, lawnmower, john-deere

I need a riding mower. I am low on dollars and my neighbour has a year-old John Deere that needs an engine. What do I need to know about the motor to search for one? Where do I search? And would it be less expensive than buying a whole mower? Please help.

Comment: Welcome and great question!

Comment: What's the model of the mower? I'd also imagine there's a plate or stamped part or model number on the old engine too.

Comment: Good idea, as for less expensive difficult to say - if you / your family / friend have the skills then you could do (very) well if you can find a suitable second-hand engine. If you took it to a dealer/shop then you could easily end up paying the same or more than a new one which comes with a guarantee... So if you have the skills & time & patience to get all the bits, it can be a good move. Personally I pick up lots of stuff at the trash and repair / re-use.

Comment: There should  be a model and serial number plate on the engine, was purchased from Home Depot (or other mass retailer) or an authorized JD dealer? If you find the tag take a pic of it and post it.